# How can I show a specific text on a textarea?

Tags: jquery

I have one form with an textarea.

But I don't have enough space to put a large textarea.

So I decided to do that:

I inserted a textarea with small height on my form, and when someone clicks at this textarea, a new box with a bigger textarea inside, appears.

But I'm using the event Clone in JQuery because I have an option to clone my form multiple times.

The problem is that, I can insert information into multiple cloned textareas, but when I click at a specific textarea, it doesn't show the current value from this textarea.

I just want to add multiple textareas with information, and click again at a specific textarea and see the current value from this textarea, inside the opened Box, how can I do that?

JsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/3RLkE/

Code from the box:

```
.descBox
{
   display:none;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    position: fixed;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Script code

```
  var Element=null;
      $(".clone").click(function(){
          $(".txtarea:first").clone(true).appendTo(".test");
          $('#txtareavalue').val('');
          $('.txtarea:last').val('');
      });

      $(".txtarea").click(function(){
          Element= $(this);
          $(".descBox").toggle();
      });

      $(".save").click(function(){
      $(".descBox").toggle();


      Element.val($('#txtareavalue').val());
      Element.text($('#txtareavalue').val());

      $('#txtareavalue').val('');
  });
```

HTML

```
  <div class="test">
     <input type="button" class="clone" value="clone" />

     <textarea type="text" class="txtarea"></textarea>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the contents of that text area.

```
$(".txtarea").click(function(){
    Element= $(this);
    $(".descBox").toggle();
    $('#txtareavalue').val(Element.val());
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3RLkE/2/

Comment: and this code is different from what I gave you how?

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it like this:

```
$(".txtarea").click(function(){
 Element= $(this);
$(".descBox textarea").val(Element.val());
$(".descBox").toggle();
})
```

Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: What i want to do is when i click again at a textarea, to show the value from the current textarea, this code is not working :/